# jQuery Sortable linked lists spilling outside container as they expand?

Tags: jquery, html

This I'm assuming is a relatively trivial problem.

I have two connected sortable lists, each inside a seperate fixed DIV.

I have the DIVs set to overflow:scroll-y.

As I add LI objects to a list, instead of the expected behaviour (expected by me) of a scroll bar appearing and the bottom of the list being neatly hidden, the list spills out of the DIV.

How can I prevent that from occuring?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $("#list1, #list2").sortable({
            connectWith: '.connectedSortable'
        }).disableSelection();

    });


<div style="padding:10px;background-color:rgb(0,0,0); width:300px; height:100px; overflow:scroll-y;">
<ul id="list1" class="connectedSortable" style="width:100px; height:10px;background-color:rgb(100,100,100);">

</ul>
</div>
<div style="padding:10px;background-color:rgb(0,0,0); width:300px;margin-top:100px;">
<ul id="list2" class="connectedSortable" style="width:300px;">
    <li>BOX1</li>
    <li>BOX2</li>
    <li>BOX3</li>
    <li>BOX4</li>
    <li>BOX5</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Interestingly, if I change overflow to hidden or scroll it "works" but when dragging from one container to the other the LI disappears as it gets dragged from the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `overflow-y:scroll` in the style rather than `overflow:scroll-y`

Comment: of course, so obvious! and embarassingly I've used it extensively.  Must've been a brain cramp!

Answer (score 1):

It should be `overflow-y:scroll;` not `overflow:scroll-y;`

It's a CSS3 property, but it has wide support.